# Custom doctrine behavior

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, symfony-1.4

Basically, I need to create a behavior that adds a table and a one-to-many relation to a relation. For example:

```
Event:
  columns: ~
  actAs:
     Recurrent: ~
```

Which would be the same as:

```
Event:
  columns: ~

EventRecurrent:
  columns:
    event_id: integer(4)
  relations:
    Event: 
      local: event_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: RecurrentDates
```

This is quite the same as what I18n template does, thought it doesn't generate files, whereas I need to have **EventRecurrent** and **EventRecurrentTable** classes generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is so complex, you wont find an answer here on Stack Overflow: you will need very deep understanding of how Doctrine works to achieve this.

Since you want to be able to to modify the tables, I think you're faster off by just defining the models in your model.

If this is not acceptable for your use case, I'd just dive into it: You'll need your own `Doctrine_Template`, probably is `Doctrine_Template_I18n` a good place to start. This `Doctrine_Template_I18n` in turn uses the `Doctrine_I18n` class which extends `Doctrine_Record_Generator`.
If you look at the options of this generator, there's an option "generateFiles": setting this to `true` probably does what you want. But you'll need a lot of trial and error, probably :)

Comment: I turned out not to be complex after all, eventually I took the Versinable behavior and modified it to my needs. I had a lot of trial and error (mostly with migrations) with generateFiles turned to true, btw. Finally, I figured I don't actually need the files, so I turned it off and everything worked out fine.